# No human armature

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I am just learning Blender 2.82. In the tutorial, it lists 4 different choices when you add - Armature. I don't get any choices I can only place a single bone. No human armature is available to me. What am I not doing?

Comment: Enable the rigify addon. It is now disabled by default.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you! I've got skeletons!